# SSIS Conditional Column Similar to Power Query

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, powerquery, dataflowtask

im a little new to SSIS coming from using Power Query in Excel a lot. Is it possible to create a conditional column in SSIS, similar to how you can in Power Query.

For example in Power Query you can create a conditional column to say IF column [FileName] contains USA, Canada, United States, America = "North America" else "null". It would create a new column with North America and anything that doesn't meet the criteria, it would be a null. Is something like this possible in SSIS. I have tried used the Substring and Findstring however it doesnt do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're looking for a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression) condition like this in `derived column`:

```
(FINDSTRING([Name], "USA", 1) > 0) || (FINDSTRING([Name], "Canada", 1) > 0) || (FINDSTRING([Name], "United States", 1) > 0) || (FINDSTRING([Name], "America", 1) > 0) ? "North America" :  NULL(DT_WSTR, 13)
```

To explain it, I am indenting it as:

```
(FINDSTRING([Name], "USA", 1) > 0) || 
(FINDSTRING([Name], "Canada", 1) > 0) || 
(FINDSTRING([Name], "United States", 1) > 0) || 
(FINDSTRING([Name], "America", 1) > 0) ? "North America" : 
                                          NULL(DT_WSTR, 13)
```

To modify it further, you can use the following guide:

- For Contains `like '%value%'` : `FINDSTRING(col, "value", 1) > 0`
- Start with `like 'value%'` : `FINDSTRING(col, "value", 1) == 1`
- End with `like '%value'` : `REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(col), X))  == "value"`

source: [sqlservercentral blog](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/toddmcdermid/2012/05/22/basic-ssis-equivalents-to-t-sqls-like/)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Within a data flow task (aka data pump) there is a Derived Column component where you can add columns to your data flow and include a custom expression.

Comment: Yes I've tried using the derived column within the data flow task using the substring and findstring expressions however, I can't seem to get it to do what I need it to do. Would you know how that expression would be wrote?